# SQL - Using a Macro Variable within an Exec statement

Tags: sql

Comes up with the error saying I need to declare the @today Macro variable?

```
DECLARE @Table_Name VARCHAR(MAX);    
DECLARE @Today DATE = '2023-09-01';    
SET @Table_Name = (
SELECT 'Servername.[databasename].[dbo].[tablename]')

declare @sql varchar(500)
        
set @sql = '    
SELECT SUM([Current Balance]) AS PurchaseBalance,@TODAY as PurchaseMonth from ' + @table_name

exec (@sql)
```

Hoping for @today to become the purchasemonth within the exec sql statement

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Please tag it. Answers can vary materially between each.

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server would interpet @Today as part of the string and try tu run  the select, but it wouldn't know it, as it is not part of the session, so you need to add it to the string.

```
DECLARE @Table_Name VARCHAR(MAX);    
DECLARE @Today DATE = '2023-09-01';    
SET @Table_Name =  'Servername.[databasename].[dbo].[tablename]'

declare @sql varchar(500)
        
set @sql = '    
SELECT SUM([Current Balance]) AS PurchaseBalance,'+ QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(23), @Today, 121), '"') + ' as PurchaseMonth from ' + @table_name

exec (@sql)
```

Comment: Legend thank you